# Getting feeds for Public Pages of Facebook using Spring Social or Restfb

Tags: facebook-graph-api, spring-social, restfb, spring-social-facebook

I need to build a server which would get the public feed details of various companies/ brands. For example, I should be able to get the feed for last one week for Cocacola (facebook.com/cocacolaindia) , Pepsi, Levis etc. Since I am only looking for public feeds I thought I dont need to use OAuth for authorization but I see no other way to get this info. For example - i tried below code but none of last three ways works.

```
        String acessTok = "{my app id}|{app seceret key}"; //App level token

    Facebook facebook = new FacebookTemplate(acessTok);

    FacebookProfile profile = facebook.userOperations().getUserProfile("cocacolaIndia");

    Page page = facebook.pageOperations().getPage("cocacolaIndia");

    List<Post> list= facebook.feedOperations().getFeed("cocacolaIndia");
```

Is there a way out ? I can use httpurl to call http://graph.facebook.com/ and
parse the json but then would need my own api's to get different fields which I don't want to do..

Answer (score 0):

You can use an App Access Token. Here's some RestFB example.

```js
AccessToken accessToken = new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainAppAccessToken(MY_APP_ID, MY_APP_SECRET);
```

Now you can build your `FacebookClient` with this new access token.

With `fetchConnection` you can fetch the public posts from the desired "fanpage".

Answer (score 0):

I had the same Problem.
I was trying to access the public Posts of an Facebook Page only with the `AppId` and `AppSecret`.

The following worked for me:

```
private Facebook facebook;
...
this.facebook = new FacebookTemplate("{AppId}|{AppSecret}");
...
Collection<Post> posts =this.facebook.feedOperations().getPosts("{PageId}");
```

I hope this is helpful.